# Do the colors of the "Zither strings" in VS 2013 signify something? If so, what?

Tags: colors, ide, visual-studio-2013, code-editor

I like the "zither strings" that Visual Studio 2013 displays, that help visually align the braces in try / using / while / etc. blocks of code. I also enjoy them aesthetically, as they appear in different visual representations of points along the electromagnetic spectrum:

[image]

But, are those colors "more than a pretty face"? In the screen shot above, I see, from left to right, gray, teal, midnight blue, grey, gray, grey, gray, purple, and grey again. Is this just to help differentiate one line from another? If so, why are several succeeding lines the same hue (as far as I can tell)?

Or, do the colors signify something, such as teal for classes, midnight blue for methods, purple for while, and gr[a,e]y for everything else?

Comment: These lines are coming from an add-in. Visual Studio doesn't have them by default. Are  you running CodeRush (https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/) or Indent Guide (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30?SRC=VSIDE). I'm not aware of any meaning associated to their colorization.

Comment: Coderush has the option to assign meaning to these lines it seems (upon further investigation... under `Options\Editing\Painting\Structural Highlighting`

Comment: No, I'm not using CodeRush, and have never heard of Indent Guide; could they be a Resharper thing? That I do use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are part of the **Productivity Power Tools for VS2013** (see [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)).  Specifically they are part of the **Structure Visualizer** feature.

There does seem to be some meaning in the colours.  I haven't been able to find a definitive list of colours, but I've noticed the following:

- Grey for general blocks, like namespaces, try / catch blocks and using
  blocks.  The grey for namespaces seems to be a bit darker than other block types.
- Teal for classes
- Blue for methods
- Green for conditional blocks (if / then, switch)
- Purple for looping blocks (for, foreach)

You can turn the lines on and off in the Productivity Power Tools section of the Options dialog.